# New-ADuser force to change password at next logon

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell

I want to use Powershell New-ADuser to add new user in that, new user must have change password at first time logon. I find the attribute "-ChangePasswordAtLogon" but when I use it, new user still not enable option change password at first time login.

```
New-ADUser -Name "Nguyen Van Nam" -GivenName "Nguyen Van" -Surname Nam -SamAccountName namnv -UserPrincipalName namnv@queencenter.local -ChangePasswordAtLogon 1 -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "P@ssw0rd" -AsPlainText -Force) -PassThru | Enable-ADAccount
```

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of [ChangePasswordAtLogon not applying on New-ADUser when enabled is false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35141099/changepasswordatlogon-not-applying-on-new-aduser-when-enabled-is-false?rq=1)

Comment: Use `ChangePasswordAtLogon` in the next line, etc.

Answer (score 1):

We had to do this recently for all our users. Essentially something like:

```
$myUser = Get-ADUser [your filter or search parameters; embed in a foreach if you need to]
$myUser.pwdLastSet = 0
Set-ADUser -Instance $myUser
```

This will do the trick.